# Elegantly make overlapped DIVs order by dom's order

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js

```
<div id="cards">
  <div class="card">card 1</div>
  <div class="card">card 2</div>
</div>

#cards { position: relative }
.card { position: absolute; left: 0 }
```

I was trying to make a deck of cards.

But, when I use the above way, "card 2" became the most front one.

Are there any elegant way to make overlapped DIVs order by dom's order?

p.s. I was using knockout.js as my framework and template engine.I've considered to prepend the latter card into #cards with jQuery, which means I have to give up "foreach" in template engine, or store my models in reverse order. That would be ugly.

p.s.2 Ways like manually set div's z-index is the last choice.

Comment: That's the way the DOM works, the lower elements in the DOM tree will overlap the higher ones, unless you use z-indexing. Use it to your advantage and reverse the order of your cards instead of using hacks and complex codes :)

Comment: Thanks Kyle, I just want to make sure there is no other way

Answer (score 4):

That's the way the DOM works, the lower elements in the DOM tree will overlap the higher ones, unless you use z-indexing.

Use it to your advantage and reverse the order of your cards instead of using hacks and complex codes, it would end up being more things to go wrong and might not display as you intend across the different browsers.

Answer (score 2):

DOM order is last defined is on top. One way to override this is with css' `z-index` property.

The only other option is to reorder the cards to the order that matches your preference.

Comment: Thanks Korvin, I just want to make sure there is no other way

Comment: Reordering could of course be done with JavaScript, but most likely would just be z-index.